# blocks must be 2-D

Tags: python-3.x, машинное-обучение, numpy, scikit-learn

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction import DictVectorizer
from scipy.sparse import hstack
from sklearn.linear_model import Ridge

def pre_processing(series):
    series = series.str.lower()
    series = series.replace('[^a-zA-Z0-9]', ' ', regex = True)
    return(series)

train = pd.read_csv('salary_train.csv')

vec = TfidfVectorizer(min_df = 5)
X_train_text = vec.fit_transform(pre_processing(train['FullDescription']))

train['LocationNormalized'].fillna('nan', inplace=True)
train['ContractTime'].fillna('nan', inplace=True)

enc = DictVectorizer()
X_train_categ = enc.fit_transform(train[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))

X_train = hstack( X_train_text, X_train_categ)

y_train = train['SalaryNormalized']
model = Ridge(alpha = 1, random_state = 241)
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

test = read_csv('salary_test_mini.csv')
X_test_text = vec.fit_transform(pre_processing(test['FullDescription']))
X_test_categ = enc.transform(test[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
X_test = hstack(X_test_text, X_test_categ)
y_test = model.predict(X_test)
print(y_test)
```

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()

```
     21 X_train_categ = enc.fit_transform(train[['LocationNormalized', 'ContractTime']].to_dict('records'))
     22 
---> 23 X_train = hstack( X_train_text, X_train_categ)
     24 
     25 y_train = train['SalaryNormalized']

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    462 
    463     """
--> 464     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    465 
    466 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\scipy\sparse\construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    545 
    546     if blocks.ndim != 2:
--> 547         raise ValueError('blocks must be 2-D')
    548 
    549     M,N = blocks.shape
```

ValueError: blocks must be 2-D

Почему возникает эта ошибка

Comment: Я проверил массивы с помощью ndim, и эти массивы двумерные

Comment: можете привести пример ваших входных данных?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте объединить матрицы в скобки:

```
X_test = hstack((X_test_text, X_test_categ))
```